# How to use compressed archive when script expects uncompressed

Tags: bash, io-redirection, tar

I'm currently working on a program which calls a script, that converts NCBI Blast Databases from BLASTDB format to FASTA format. This script normally expects to run within a directory of an uncompressed BLASTDB database and takes the -db option to clarify which database (consisting of multiple files all having the same name, but different endings) should be converted.

Because I have very limited storage on the server I'd like to only save the databases in a compressed archive, so my question is: Is there any way to use that script within that archive or is it possible (maybe via bash redirection?) to directly stream that uncompressed archive into that script?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You can mount your archive with [fuse-archive](https://github.com/google/fuse-archive):

```
mkdir /mnt/some-directory
fuse-archive your-archive.tar.gz /mnt/some-directory
```

But you can repack archive contents into SquashFS file and likely you'll get better performance, because unlike tar, SquashFS is a compressed filesystem which is designed for random access. Use [`tar2sqfs` tool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/tar2sqfs.1.html) to repack:

```
zcat your-archive.tar.gz | tar2sqfs -c xz -b 1048576 mountable-archive.squashfs
```

Then, either as root:

```
mount -t squashfs mountable-archive.squashfs /mnt/some-directory
```

or as normal user, using [squashfuse](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/squashfuse.1.html):

```
squashfuse mountable-archive.squashfs /mnt/some-directory
```

The SquashFS mounted as root will deliver the best performance of all three methods.

---

In the mounted directory `/mnt/some-directory` you'll find the contents of the archive and you can run any scripts. But notice in any case this will be *read only* directory. If you need to write into this directory (for example, create or update files), you'll need to add another mount using `overlayfs` (or any other overlay mounter, like `aufs`):

```
mkdir /mnt/upper
mkdir /mnt/work
mkdir /mnt/readwrite-directory

mount -t overlay -o upperdir=/mnt/upperdir,lowerdir=/mnt/some-directory,workdir=/mnt/work mountable-archive-rw /mnt/readwrite-directory
```

Then work within this `/mnt/readwrite-directory`. It fill have all objects from the archive, but it is read-write; any new files or updates will be written into `/mnt/upper`, while `/mnt/some-directory` is the read-only squashfs or fuse-archive mount point from previous step.

Comment: +1 for nice, comprehensive answer that also mentions SquashFS and overlayFS. Note that you can avoid squashfuse: `udisksctl loop-setup --read-only --file mountable-archive.squashfs` works well.

Comment: I never knew udisks has a command line client :)

Comment: it's also been a relatively recent discovery for me. It's very handy. I can now create filesystem images without sudo!

Answer (score 0):

No. The [relevant documentation](https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/documents/blastdb.html) clearly states that:

> The compressed files downloaded must be inflated with gzip or other decompress
> tools. The BLAST database files can then be extracted out of the resulting tar
> file using the tar utility on Unix/Linux, or WinZip and StuffIt Expander on
> Windows and Macintosh platforms, respectively.

If this were actually a script, you could get around it by using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) if your shell supports it:

```
command <(zcat file.gz)
```

That would allow `command` to process `file.gz` as though it were not compressed. Unfortunately, it isn't your script that uses the DB, it's the blast executable and that will expect it to be uncompressed because you're not passing the DB files as arguments so you can't get around it.

---

That said, [Nikita Kipriyanov's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727888/22222) of squshfs makes a lot of sense!